# IONIC 4 + Laravel CORS

Tags: laravel-5, cors, ionic4

ok, i have been searching the web for hours now and found a lot of results but no working ones :(

I am developing a app in ionic 4. Up till now i was using my local "api" to test (which works) but now i want to test it with the live version which is build using laravel - it is a exact copy of the local version but then live on the domain.

I have installed https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors to handle the cors and when i test the cors on https://www.test-cors.org it shows:

```
date: Fri, 07 Jun 2019 22:18:39 GMT
content-encoding: gzip
server: Google Frontend
access-control-allow-origin: *
etag: "1rO4KQ"
allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
content-type: text/html
status: 200
x-cloud-trace-context: c463d031b08229c22feccaba743c28a5
cache-control: public, max-age=600
access-control-allow-headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,content-type
expires: Fri, 07 Jun 2019 22:28:39 GMT
```

so i guess my server side cors is ok. Now in ionic im doing the following:

```
  getPartnersForZipcode(zipcode: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'/search-partners', {zipcode:zipcode}, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(results => results),
);
```

}

as http options im using

```
  httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
})
```

};
*I tried it also with no headers, also with only content type etc.. none made a difference

....i dont know whats happening... why do my requests dont work in ionic?

which is using the package 
`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';`

In postman i get a good response with data
[image]

but in ionic (using ionic --serve and devapp on device (ios)) im getting CORS error
[image]

Comment: The server is responding to the OPTIONS requests with a 405 Method Not Allowed error. That’s the problem you need to fix. And the fact the server is responding with a 405 to OPTIONS requests is unrelated to your laravel-cors settings, and unrelated to the headers being sent back to the browser. The browser isn’t giving you an error; instead the server is. You need to configure that server to allow OPTIONS requests. The code where that needs to be done in separate from your laravel-cors code.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that options routes are not allowed by laravel. and i dont know how to allow them?

Comment: Use the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * Extension in google chrome to avoid Cors Error, Or Use Ionic Native HTTP instead of angular http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok im posting this for users who have the same problem.

For some reason a POST from ionic using the header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` (what is default) will result in this error.

i have changed this to

```
  httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
})
```

};

And now i get data back from the webserver. This is not the best solution but for now it will do.